# Density function of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, density-function

If I have the following density function of a continuous random variable
$$ f(y) = cy , \qquad 0 \leq y \leq 1 .$$

is it possible to determine what c is without any further information?

Comment: The integral of the density function of a continuous random variable over its domain is equal to one.

Comment: Yes, because by definition $f$ must satisfy
$$\int_0^1 f(y)dy =1 $$